# Java's Native Swing Web Browser

Tags: java, embedded-browser

Several hours ago I have found a very interesting technology in area of Java's embedded browsers - Native Swing (includes Cross-platform Web Browser, Flash Player, HTML Editor, Multimedia Player and more).

http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html

It works excellent!

Is it true that this technology is based on the launching of current operational system's default browser within java application? 
(http://blog.macrominds.de/2010/03/embedded-gecko-browser-in-java-application-with-djnativeswing/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when something is too perfect, it's almost allways has some drawback. Be it in java or any other system, when you get a full web browser, it's allways just an interface for the default web brower. Windows calls it OLE (Object Linking and Embedding) a technoclogy to insert objects from another application (like a web browser or an excel table) to your app.

If you want a REAL web browser I'm afraid you have to write your own.

Comment: *"If you want a REAL web browser I'm afraid you have to write your own."*  1) If your *user* wants a browser they want their default *MyBrowser* rather than something dreamed up by a highly caffeinated developer. 2) Most of the users would prefer to see *MyBrowser* as a free floating entity rather than wrapped in our GUI. 3) How many man years have you got to devote to developing this UA? (+1 nonetheless.)

Comment: Thank you all for answers. They were very useful.